# Cannot access internet via Wi-Fi on YU Yureka running Lollipop

Tags: wi-fi, 5.0-lollipop, reboot, micromax-yu-yureka

I have a YU Yureka mobile which upgraded to Android Lollipop version. I have been regularly using my office's Wi-Fi connection. For some days, the phone is showing that Wi-Fi is connected, but I can't access the Internet through Wi-Fi. When I connect the phone to a Wi-Fi network, I can access Internet for 30 seconds and then my phone would hang and then restart automatically.

There are more than twenty employees in my office, but only my phone has this problem. I have done soft reset and hard reset to solve the issue. It  works perfectly for Mobile data network.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Tweaking the DNS might solve the issue. Go to Settings>>Wi-Fi and turn on the Wi-Fi. If the network is known, 'forget' it and then connect it back. Once the password window pops up, click on 'Advanced options' and select 'Static' from the IP settings drop-down menu. Then scroll down and enter the IP address of the DNS server you would like to use in DNS1 and DNS2 box. Now enter your Wi-Fi password and connect it.